# Dual Monitor Setup from One HDMI port

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a laptop with an Nvidia GeForce GTX1650 that has only one HDMI Port.
I have two monitors

1. Dell P2720DC
2. Samsung S24F350FH

I need to know can my graphic card extended to these two monitors at the same time, and if so what's the best way to connect these two displays with my laptop (what cables or adapter do I need).

Also, I would like to keep the image on my Dell monitor at QHD 60Hz is that possible?

If there's a way to connect these monitors can you please also list the resolution I will be able to transmit to these displays and at what refresh rate (Hz).

Comment: The GeForce GTX1650 is listed a supporting DVI, HDMI and DisplayPort. How come yours has only HDMI?

Comment: @harrymc that's how it came with my laptop. check these pics to see ports configuration https://notebooky.heureka.cz/hp-pavilion-gaming-15-ec0009-8rv19ea/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The Dell P2720DC has Type C input which could be daisy-chained via the DisplayPort output on the Dell into the DisplayPort input of the Samsung S24F350FH.</s>[Edit: It doesn't have one] You could use Type C alternate mode video output as an alternative to HDMI.

Correction:

Ports on the Dell:

> 1. Power connector | 2. Security-lock slot | 3. Stand lock feature | 4. HDMI 1.4 port | 5. DisplayPort 1.2 (in) | 6. DisplayPort 1.2 (out) | 7. USB-C port | 8. USB 2.0 downstream ports (x2 - rear) | 9. USB 3.0 downstream ports (x2 - side)

Ports on the Samsung:

> 1x HDMI, 1x VGA

Looks like you're out of luck, the FW model samsung monitor had the DisplayPort input. Converters will break the MST chain, so you would need to buy a Type-C adapter with dual HDMI outputs: [https://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Converter-Compatible-Windows-Android/dp/B0816THCQH/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0816THCQH)

Comment: If you're saying to connect the USB-C right to my laptop, I think that might not work. I have tried that option but didn't work. Looks like the USB-C on my laptop is data transfer capable only.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-SuperSpeed-Adapter-Windows/dp/B00BPEV1XK You could try these bizzare USB video cards as a last resort.

Comment: https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66256 These devices apparently aren't video cards but simply forward video output from the GPU via USB. They present lag if large portions of the screen are redrawn and games don't work well. This might be your only option, though.

Comment: DisplayLink adapter are GPUs. They do not rely on the built-in GPU in any way. That’s why they could indeed by used here. They’re only suitable for office applications though.

Comment: This is my work setup and I don't intend to ever play games with these monitors. I just kinda want to be sure I can use the FHD resolution at 60Hz on my Samsung monitor if I connect via the DisplayLink adapter.

Comment: @James, the 2560x1440 max resolution chipset appears to support 60Hz operation as quoted on their design wins listing: https://www.displaylink.com/products/hot-products, just avoid their USB 2.0 1x5 chipset which only goes up to 2048 x 1152 and you should have 60Hz working.

Comment: @Daniel, these devices appear to be using the Indirect Display Driver model for their drivers
(The Indirect Display Driver Model is an API introduced with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update intended to allow user-mode drivers to be created that can display content on monitors that are not connected to a traditional display adapter.)
If you still have doubts to the authenticity of the claim that it functions just like miracast, refer to the explanation by the opensource driver effort at https://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/

Answer (score 0):

There is only one series of products that I’m aware of that solve this general problem: Matrox Dual/TripleHead2Go.

*However*, none of the models features a HDMI input. Additionally, you could only use the same resolution on both displays and they would be presented to your PC as a single display.

Unlike DisplayPort, HDMI does not feature Multi-Stream Transport.

**tl;dr**: What you want cannot be accomplished.

/edit: For completeness sake, as Mahir Ahmed suggested on [his answer](https://superuser.com/a/1562407/219095), a DisplayLink adapter would allow you to add an additional independent video output to your PC. DisplayLink adapter are not suitable for gaming though. Video playback usually work reasonably well, but that’s it.

Comment: Well, I don't intend to play games on these monitors. I will be using for my work related stuff, things like programming, reading, web surfing, and some youtube.